# Android ViewPager setPageTransformer not working after once we visit all item of view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation

I am creating slideshow using ViewPager. I want an fade animation when view pager item changes.

I have used method **setPageTransformer** to set Animation.

```
viewpager.setPageTransformer(false, new FadePageTransformer());
```

It is showing animation first time when run slideshow.

But after once slideshow overs,second time animation is not working.

I am not able to understand why animation not working second time.

Please help someone if anyone has faced this issue.
Thanks